# does _ represent local variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am pretty new to ReactiveCocoa and Objective-C. I see that in the following code there is usage of `_subscribeCommand` but there isn't a place where it was declared. It coincides with the `subscribeCommand` method. So is this a local variable?

```
- (RACCommand *)subscribeCommand {
  if (!_subscribeCommand) {
      NSString *email = self.email;
      _subscribeCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:self.emailValidSignal signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
          return [SubscribeViewModel postEmail:email];
      }];
  }
  return _subscribeCommand;
}
```

Full code were found in this tutorial
http://codeblog.shape.dk/blog/2013/12/05/reactivecocoa-essentials-understanding-and-using-raccommand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a property on a class, Objective-C will create an instance variable with the same name as the property but with an underscore prefix.  In the tutorial you link to there is a `subscribeCommand` property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) RACCommand *subscribeCommand;
```

Within the class you can access this property using the getters/setters using `self.subscribeCommand` or directly access the variable using `_subscribeCommand`.

If you directly access the instance variable you are bypassing the getter/setter, whether an explicit getter/setter in the class or the implied getter/setter that enforces the property attributes (`nonatomic`, `strong` etc).

In the example you link to, the `subscribeCommand` method is an explicit getter for the `subscribeCommand` property.  There is no `setSubscribeCommand` method so the default setter will be used (which will enforce the `strong` and `nonatomic` attributes of the property).